# populating data using cursor in oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms

I have created a block with 4 text items which i have to populate using a cursor.

I have written a code in the same blocks post-query trigger which is as follows:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR D_COMM_DET IS
        SELECT COMM_SRNO, COMM_SUB_SRNO, COMM_REASON 
        FROM CUST_COMM
        WHERE LEAD_ID = :INQUIRY.INQ_ID; -- master block "INQUIRY"
BEGIN

    GO_BLOCK('DISPLAY_DET');
    CLEAR_BLOCK('NO_VALIDATE');
    FIRST_RECORD;
    FOR CUR IN D_COMM_DET 
    LOOP
    :DISPLAY_COMM_DET.A_COMM_SRNO := CUR.COMM_SRNO;
    :DISPLAY_COMM_DET.A_COMM_SUB_SRNO := CUR.COMM_SUB_SRNO;
    :DISPLAY_COMM_DET.A_COMM_REASON := CUR.COMM_REASON;
    NEXT_RECORD;
    END LOOP;
    FIRST_RECORD;

END;
```

But this is not populating the data in the text items neither it is showing any errors.
Can anyone help regarding the same.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you right. If you need to display reason name from other table, then POST-QUERY trigger is right, but on DISPLAY_COMM_DET block.

Let this block as a detail block based on CUST_COMM table. Create non database item NDB_COMM_REASON_VALUE. Create POST-QUERY trigger on DISPLAY_COMM_DET block like this:

```
declare
  cursor c_reason is
    select comm_value
      from common_master
      where comm_reason = :display_comm_det.comm_reason;
begin
  open c_reason;
  fetch c_reason into :display_comm_det.ndb_comm_reason_value;
  close c_reason;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  Now i am facing a new problem. I have two parts in which i save my data in the table. One is Scheduled data and one is Actual data. The scheduled data is stored prior to actual data. Now here when i save the Scheduled data and try to populate data using cursor, I am getting 'No data found' error. I do not have any condition for displaying the data fetched fgrom the cursor. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Typical reason for No_DATA_FOUND is that SELECT INTO construct selected no rows. Either your select is bad or you have no data.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use restricted builtin procedures like GO_BLOCK, CLEAR_BLOCK, NEXT_RECORD in POST-QUERY trigger.

In your case make DISPLAY_COMM_DET block a detail block to INQUIRY block.

1. Add LEAD_ID item to DISPLAY_COMM_DET block. It can be hidden (Visible=No)
2. Set DISPLAY_COMM_DET as a database block based on CUST_COMM table
3. Create a  relation on INQUIRY block with relation INQUIRY.INQ_ID=DISPLAY_COMM_DET.LEAD_ID.

Delete POST-QUERY trigger, you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use restricted builtin procedures like GO_BLOCK, CLEAR_BLOCK, NEXT_RECORD in POST-QUERY trigger.

Write Execute_Query and the mentioned code in When-Button-Pressed Trigger.